# Making images drop in android

Tags: java, android

I am making an android game which needs to display some different images.
I need to make a method that keeps on generating images from a resource in the drawable directory and then drop the images from the top of the screen to the bottom. I also need that each image should have an id "image-1" "image-2" in which the index number goes higher once more images are created as an integer. I also need them to be generated at different locations at the top of the screen and drop with a specified speed. Once they hit the bottom, I want a method to be executed like:

```
public void touchedGround() {
//My code
}
```

I am using this code so far:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GameScreenActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gamescreen);
    generateParachuters(savedInstanceState);
}

private void generateParachuters(Bundle icicle) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "generating images", 10).show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know one way to do it, but it requires a lot more code then what you're probably looking for. But hey, here goes.

1. Create a class for your falling object, which I'm guessing is a `Parachuter`. This class will have an X and Y variable to keep track of where it is on the screen. You can then have a `tick` method, which will increase the Y variable by however fast you want it to fall. You can also have them keep track of a integer ID if you want.
2. Create a list that will hold the `Parachuter` objects. I use an ArrayList. This way you create a `Parachuter` when needed and add it to the list. Cycle through the list to draw each one.
3. You need something to draw the `Parachuter`s with. Personally, I use `Canvas` from `SurfaceView`.
4. You'll need a looping animation. Loop through, each time drawing the `Parachuter`s and calling `tick` on each one.
5. During the loop, you can check the position of each `Parachuter`. If its position goes beyond `Canvas.getHeight()`, remove the image from the list.

Well, that's quite a bit there. Ask me if you need further clarification.

**UPDATE**: [Here's a fully-working example](http://bpcp.angelfire.com/example.zip).

**UPDATE 2**:

```
//Check right edge of screen
for (int i = 0; i < parachuters.size(); i++)
{
    if (parachuters.get(i).getX() > canvas.getWidth())
        //Do whatever it is you want
}
```

Comment: Example code and projects can be found at http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-ii,160.html and http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/LunarLander/index.html

Comment: I tried to use the sample code and projects, but without luck. I didn't get anything out of it. Could you post me some code of how you would do it??? I have made a custom class in which i call "Parachuter.java" And that is my custom "ImageView", kind of.

Comment: Thanks so much, got it working, but i need to make a certain method repeat itself every second, how can i do this? Cause i need it to draw the images at different locations at the top of the screen and then fall down, and generate parachuters every second, how is this possible???

Comment: How can i check when a parachuter is at the edge of the screen and then execute some code???

Comment: Just write a method that checks the location of the parachuter, and check if it's at the edge. The code under the Remove comment is how you can check if it's at the bottom edge.

Comment: For timing something, you can use the system clock, and then execute a method once a second has passed. You can also check this out: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html

Comment: Thanks, but i need to know When it is at the left edge of the screen instead of the Bottom edge, how can i do this???

Comment: Well, think about it. If it's at the left of the screen, what is its X position? It's zero. Check if the object's X position is less than 0. More depending on the coordinates of the image.

Comment: Yes, except you're checking against canvas.getWidth().

Comment: I'm not getting it to work as i want, could you write a method that deletes the parachuter and executes a method once a parachuter has reached the right edge of the screen please??? And tell me more percise what to do??? I'm new with games you see

Comment: i've come up with another solution, but i'll try that anyways. I basically made the exact same code as you:-D